# Issue with Django : "NoReverseMatch at /myapp/accueil"

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I searched a bit through the web but nobody seemed to get the same issue as me, mine seems to be "too simple", but I can't find the mistake.

I use the latest version of Django, with windows. I started a project named "tesutooo", with a single app named "myapp".
At the root of the project, I have a dir named "templates/" that I use for as a basis for the others.
I have my templates in "myapp/templates/myapp/"

So my issue is between "tesutooo/templates/base.html" and "tesutoo/myapp/templates/myapp/accueil.html"

Here is my code :

tesutoo/tesutoo/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

tesutoo/myapp/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('accueil', views.accueil),
    path('date', views.date),
]
```

tesutoo/myapp/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from datetime import datetime

def accueil(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/accueil.html')

def date(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/date.html', {'date': datetime.now()})
```

tesutoo/templates/base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}Mon projet Django ou je fais un peu c'que j'veux mdr{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>Mon projet qui déchire sa cera</header>
    <nav id="nav_gen">
            {% block nav %}
            <ul>
                <a href="{% url 'myapp.views.accueil' %}">Accueil</a>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <a href="{% url 'myapp.views.date' %}">Date</a>
            </ul>
            <!-- <ul>
                <a href="{% url "Bibliothèque" %}">Bibliothèque</a>
            </ul> -->
        {% endblock %}
    </nav>
    <section id="content">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </section>
<footer>&copy; Projet de guigui</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

tesutooo/myapp/templates/myapp/accueil.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} My app mon gars ! Accueil{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <p>C'est l'accueil ici ! Regarde à gauche y a des dauphins ! Euh... des liens !</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the traceback :
[A screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObhW4.png)

Answer (score 0):

add namespace to the include

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp')),
]
```

add name to the specific views:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('accueil', views.accueil, name='accueil'),
    path('date', views.date, name='date'),
]
```

then to use it use `{%url <namespace>:<name> %}` e.g.,

```
{% url 'myapp:accueil' %}
```

Comment: Okay so I tried to do so, but Django said : "TypeError: _path() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespace'"
Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: Namespace is parameter of the include. Sorry

Comment: Yes I figured it out by myself but now it says dis 
"'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead."

Comment: i'll try to figure out how to bypass this error, I'lls say to you if I manage to do so and how. But if yoiu have an idea before, please tell me

Comment: Okay so apparently the correct line was :
" path('myapp/', include(('myapp.urls', 'myapp'), namespace='myapp')), "

Answer (score 0):

In template dynamic url you have to use

```
{% url 'myapp:accueil' %}
```

because this is the convension as Mr. Eran described you in other answer.

and you have to use `app_name = 'your_app_name'` in your app url **tesutoo/myapp/urls.py** and the code will be like

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name='myapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('accueil', views.accueil),
    path('date', views.date),
]
```